# Deciphering delay in codes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

Can you please help me in understanding how to determine the delay while deciphering codes using appropriate examples ?

I am trying to follow the definition given in the book [*Codes and Automata*](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/LivreCodes/Codes.html) by Jean Berstel, Dominique Perrin and Christophe Reutenauer, but I don't seem to follow it.

A subset $X$ of $A^{+}$ is said to have a finite deciphering delay if there exists an integer $d\geq0$ such that the following condition holds : For $x,x'\in X$ ,$y\in X^{d}$, $y'\in X^{*}$,  $xy$ is a prefix of $x'y'$ implies $x=x'$.

A few examples that I came across in various books are as follows:
            The set {${ab,abb,baab}$} has a delay one. 
            The set $ba^*$ has delay one.
            The set {$aa,ba,b$} is a finite code with infinite delay.
The set {$a,a^{k}b$} has delay k.

I am unable to relate the definition to the examples given. It will be of great help if someone can explain this to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Here are some details for two of your examples. You should then be able to uderstand the two other ones.

The set {$aa,ba,b$} is a finite code with infinite deciphering delay. Take $x = b$, $x' = ba$. Now, for all $d \geqslant 0$, $(aa)^d \in X^d$, whence $x(aa)^d, x'(aa)^d \in X^{d+1}$ and $x(aa)^d$ is a prefix of $x'(aa)^d$. However $x \not= x'$ and thus $X$ as infinite deciphering delay.

The set $ba^*$ has delay one. Let $x, x', y, y' \in X$. Then $x= ba^p$, $x' = ba^q$, $y= ba^r$, $y' = ba^s$ for some $p, q, r, s \geqslant 0$. Now if $xy$ is a prefix of $x'y'$, $ba^pba^r$ is a prefix of $ba^qba^s$, which implies that $p = q$. Thus $x = x'$. It follows that the delay of $X$ is $\leqslant 1$. Why is not $0$? Because $X^0 = \{1\}$ ($1$ denotes the empty word) and $b, ba \in XX^0 = X$ but $b$ is a prefix of $ba$.