# Example of encoding scheme which is not prefix-free

Tags: computer-science, information-theory, coding-theory

I am trying to give an example of an encoding scheme that is not prefix-free but for which reading-left-to-right is a valid decoder-recognizer.

I am using code alphabet $=\{0,1\}$. Source alphabet $S$ is composed of letters $\{a,b\}$

I have the simple scheme of:

a $->$ 001

b $->$ 00

Does this satisfy the question? $b$ is a prefix of $a$ but when read left-to-right the code is decodable, correct? For example, 000000100001 is still decodable when read left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not precise enough. In your example, compare the words $u = 0000$ and $v = 00100$. When you read these words from left to right, you first encounter $00$, so you may think that the first letter is $a$. However, this interpretation is correct for $u$, but not for $v$. The trick is that you are implicitely using a lookahead.

Codes that can be decoded, from left to right, with a finite lookahead
are called codes with *finite deciphering delay*. They form a class of codes intermediate between prefix codes and general codes. See the book [*Codes and Automata*](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/LivreCodes/Codes.html) by Jean Berstel, Dominique Perrin and Christophe Reutenauer.
The formal definition is also recalled in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031281/deciphering-delay-in-codes):

> A subset $X$ of $A^+$ has a *finite deciphering delay* if there exists
>   an integer $d \geqslant 0$ such that the following condition holds: For
>   $x,x'\in X$ and $y\in X^d$, $y'\in X^*$,  $xy$ is a prefix of $x'y'$
>   implies $x=x'$.

I let you verify that your example $\{00, 001\}$ is a code of deciphering delay 1. An interesting example of a finite code with no finite deciphering delay is $\{1, 10, 00\}$: when you decode a word of the form $10^n$ from left to right, you need to read the whole word to decide whether the first block is $1$ or $10$.

[1]